# how to get Date difference in postgres with date part

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, postgresql-9.1

How to get datetime difference in postgres

I am using below syntax

```
DATE_PART('hour', A_column::timestamp-B_column::timestamp )
```

I want output like this:

If `A_column=2020-05-20 00:00:00` and `B_column=2020-05-15 00:00:00` I want to get 72(in hours).

Is there any possibility to skip weekends(Saturday and Sunday) in first one, it means to get the result as 72 hours(exclude weekend hours)

If `A_column=2020-08-15 12:00:00` and `B_column=2020-08-15 00:00:00` I want to get 12(in hours).

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could write this as:

```
select extract(epoch from a_column::timestamp - b_column::timestamp) / 60 / 60
from mytable
```

Rationale: substracting the two timestamps gives you an interval; you can then turn it to a number of seconds, and do arithmetics to convert that to hours.

Comment: Is there any possibility to skip weekends(Saturday and Sunday) in first one, it means to get the result as 72 hours(exclude weekend hours)

Comment: @RUTHER: that's really a different question... for which comments are not suited. I would recommend [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for this.